# Is digital certificate with 'issued to' field as *.example.com valid?

Tags: encryption, certificates

Came across a Digital Certificate which has `issued to` field `*.example.com`

Is this a valid certificate?

Comment: Was the website you visited a subdomain of the ABC TV Network?

Comment: No .. I have added abc as alias .. basically this is a e-eCommerce sites' main url.

Comment: When you need a syntactical domain name as an example, you should [example.com](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) which is reserved for use in documentation and examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A certificate issued to `*.example.com` is a so-called "[Wildcard Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_certificate)". It is valid for all subdomains of example.com like `www.example.com`, `mail.example.com`, `forum.example.com` etc..

It would **not** be valid for the main domain (just `example.com`) or on any nested subdomains like `login.forum.example.com`. However, additional domains can be added to a certificate using the "SubjectAltName" field of the certificate. These alternative domain names do not even have to be under the same domain hierarchy.

Comment: Any information about Hostname/CN validation for such sites?

Comment: @user49149 Any *specific* questions about that topic?

Comment: Basically for host validation we get the server name (CN) and validate it, but here we will have an asterisk in place of server name. So do we skip it now for such wildcard certificates?

Comment: @user49149 RFC 6125 defines how you validate a DNS name vs. an x509 certificate. Check it out: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6125